# How can I separate text from a query result in html?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to display the result of a query in a HTML page on django. I'm getting the result expected but I would like to separate the information from a cell in 5 cells. For example: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eREYo.png).

Since this is a table, I would like to dispose this like 9030101 | 'Registo....' | 165.0 | \65.0 | None.

Sorry if the question is silly but I can't fix this.

Comment: result[1:-1].split(',')  ---- since your result is in one cell. You can just remove the brackets and split them to have a list.

Comment: Hi Antonio,
You can traverse the string to append table tags like <td> and then parse the string as html.
I hope this will help

Comment: Dont post images, post copy/pastes from your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
{% for val in response_data %}
    <td>{{val.name}}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

This is a simple way to loop the data and display it in table

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
var string = `(9030101,'REGISTO ELECTROCARDIOGRAPICO TRANSESOFAGICO - PEDIATRICO',165.0,165.0,None)`;

var regex = new RegExp(/[^',(0-9)(none)][a-zA-Z- ]*/g);
var finalText;

finalText = regex.exec(string);
alert(finalText)
```

**Happy coding :)**

Comment: I have thousands of lines like this, I can't do that for each one. But thank you :)

Comment: this is dynamic dude. it will clip text from this type of string

Comment: You didn't understand my question, it just can't be done like you said

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite incomplete, so I can only answer based on a couple assumptions.

The main assumtion is that "the result of a query" is a `queryset` or `list` (or any iterable) of `tuples`, each one representing one database row - if that's not the case then for GodOrWhoeverYouBelieveIn's sake, please edit your question wih all relevant details.

The second assumptions is that this list or queryset or whatever is named "results" in your template's context (if that's not the case etc etc...)

Then all you need are two nested loops - the outer one on `results` to get each row, the inner one on each row to get fields:

```
<table>
   {% for row in results %}
   <tr>
       {% for field in row %}
       <td>{{ field }}</td>
       {% endfor %}
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: It's exactly that bruno! Sorry for the way I made the question but I couldn't explain myself. But you helped me a lot! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help - and if that's indeed the case please feel free to accept the answer.